# Custom PHP Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I use the code below to do a "next" and "previous" navigation.  It works but even when there is 1 entry the next button shows and when there are more than 20 entries and once they have been served the code shows next and previous. How can I make it so that the next button will only show if there are more than 10 and how do I show no next and previous button if there are no more results to show:

```
       if (!isset($_GET['pg']) or !is_numeric($_GET['pg'])) {

        $startrow = 0;

       } else {
       $startrow = (int)mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pg']);
       }

       echo '<a id=pgnvg href=
      "'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.($startrow+20).'&   q='.($what).'">Next</a>';


       $prev = $startrow - 20;

       //only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
       if ($prev >= 0)
       echo '<a id=pgnvg2 href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.$prev.'">Previous</a>';
```

Comment: `(int)mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pg']);` won't do you much good - either `$_GET['pg']` is a numeric string, in which case it doesn't need escaping, or it is a non-numeric string in which case converting to an int will probably result in zero. In either case `(int) $_GET['pg']` is sufficient for converting to an int.

Answer (score 4):

you need to add a check on how many items are actually returned e.g:

```
if($itemAmount > 20) {
echo '<a id=pgnvg href=
      "'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.($startrow+20).'&   q='.($what).'">Next</a>';
}
```

otherwise the next button will always display

Comment: You also want to remove the Next link on the last page so use something a bit cleverer in the conditional statement if($current-page * $results-per-page < $total-results) { ...  $current-page is defaulted to 1 unless pg is set

Comment: Thanks for this but one problem.  After the 20th result i still see the next page when there are no other results to return.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have a variable `$itemsCount` containing the number of items into the recordset.

If you don't have one you can calculate it with a query like

```
count(*) FROM <wathever table or join> WHERE <list of conditions>
```

Further I would use a constant called `ITEMS_ON_A_PAGE` (Hope you will guess its content ;)

```
define ('ITEMS_ON_A_PAGE',20); // put it where more appropriate

...

if (!isset($_GET['pg']) or !is_numeric($_GET['pg'])) {
    $startrow = 0;
} else {
   // no need to issue a mysql query, you need an integer from a numeric variable
   $startrow = (int)$_GET['pg'];
}

$linkTemplate = '<a id="%s" href="?%s">%s</a>';
$nextPageFirstItem = $startrow + ITEMS_ON_A_PAGE;
$previousPageFirstItem = $startrow - ITEMS_ON_A_PAGE;

if ($itemsCount> $nextPageFirstItem) {
    echo printf($linkTemplate,
            'pgnvg',
            http_build_query(array('pg'=>$nextPageFirstItem,'q'=>$what)),
            'Next'
    );
}

if ($previousPageFirstItem >= 0) {
   echo printf($linkTemplate,
            'pgnvg2',
            http_build_query(array('pg'=>$previousPageFirstItem,'q'=>$what)),
            'Previous'
   );
}
```

Here there is the reference for the [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) that creates the query for you

There will be a lot of room to improve this code but, as a starting point, it would suffice ;)

Answer (score -2):

You might actually want to use a `switch` statement. Sometimes `if` statements stop working when you have too many of them and too many evaluate to be true. Just pay attention to when you want to `break;` vs not breaking (don't include `break;`).

Comment: a switch statement makes only sense if there are more than 2 options. in this case he only uses 2 if clauses, none of which could be replaced with switch. also the answer is not really relevant to the question asked

Comment: you can set switch(true), and there are 3 if statements once the user has added the appropriate test. also, with 2 `if` tests, there are technically 4 cases (the `else`s are just omitted).

Comment: Why would an `if` stop working if there are too many?  Is that a 'feature' of php?

Comment: of course it's not a feature. i don't know why they stop evaluating (or sometimes evaluated true when all of the conditions were not met), but i have seen it happen several times. it's possible something was causing a conflict. i just know when it was changed to a `switch` all of the cases were properly evaluated.